# Search/Filter for automotive search

Tags: search, lists, filter, faceted-search, automotive-ux

I'm creating a search form for an automotive website, and we want to use auto-suggest to recommend filter sets to refine the data. I've never designed search results that also incorporate search filters though, so I'm looking for advice where to start.

Data set:
900,000+ vehicle inventory

Filter sets:
Make, model, trim, year, miles, price, dealership, distance from user

The filter sets will be pre-populated from referrer data, so if they're on a Chevy Tahoe page and hit search, Chevy and Tahoe will be preselected, along with geolocation data.

What I don't know is the best way to display the current filters and/or available filters (Do I show them at all? Or only through search?) How would I show a search set with zero filters set?

Comment: Performance is priority #1 in this scenario, btw

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently spoke with  Sarah Alpern about her work on refining LinkedIn's search. They too have a great deal of data to sift through. She has written two great posts on this subject that I think you will find useful.

http://blog.linkedin.com/2008/12/02/optimizing-your-linkedin-search-experience/

http://blog.linkedin.com/2010/03/05/designing-linkedin-faceted-search/

Points I would consider for your problem:

- Left Navigation
- Execute filter on click, no "submit"
- Check boxes are easier to discover
- People related to using check marks to mark what they DO want, instead of unchecking what they do not want.
- It NEEDS to be fast

My own comments:

- Always start with something broad and have them narrow it down
- Make images and car titles prominent, people want to scan when searching, even more than usual.
- Ability to save search filters is important in a car search. Buying a car is a big thing and people like to get very knowledgable by looking around a lot.
- Ability to share the results. Same reasons above, people want to share their findings with other people who would be part of their discussion making process.